# Is there any method in SAS or SQL to extract value in column A based on the value in column B

Tags: sql, sas

tI have a able  as below :

```
acct_nbr File_ID File_Date    DOFD       Previous_DOFD      Previous_FileDate
123      1       1/1/2019    12/22/2022
123      2       1/1/2020     1/12/2023   12/22/2022         1/1/2019**
```

I want to get the **File_DATE value (1/1/2019)** in the **Previous_File_Date** column for the corresponding **File_Date(1/1/2019)** when **dofd(12/22/2022)** IS populated in Previous_DOFD field

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LAG` function to retrieve the previous value. LAG is essentially a n-value filo stack of n values at the place of the LAG function.  Caution:
You typically do not use LAG as a conditional statement or inside a conditional block.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by acct_nbr;

  previous_dofd = lag(dofd);
  previous_filedate = lag(file_date);

  if first.acct_nbr then call missing(of previous:);
run;
```

The question wasn't clear, so if `previous_filedate` is part of the incoming data set, try:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by acct_nbr;

  previous_dofd = lag(dofd);

  if previous_filedate ne lag(filedate) or first.acct_nbr then
    call missing(previous_dofd);
run;
```